# How to add multiple members (Users or Service Accounts) into a Group in GCP - Python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client, google-iam

Is there a method to add a multiple Service Accounts into a GCP Group?

I'm currently using Python and successfully adding a single user per time, as you can see in the script below.

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

# Credentials to authenticate to GCP
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('xyz.json')

# Client
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    'admin', 
    'directory_v1', 
    credentials=credentials
)

# List of SAs
accounts = [
    "user1@example.com",
    "user2@example.com",
]

# Group ID
group = 'group@example.com'

members = service.members()

for account in accounts:
    try:
        members.insert(
            groupKey=group,
            body={'email': account},
        ).execute()
        print(f"SA: {account} Success")
    except Exception as _e:
        print(f"SA: {account} Failed", _e)
```

According to the [documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/admin_directory_v1.members.html#delete:%7E:text=Identity%20Groups%20API.-,insert(groupKey%2C%20body%3DNone%2C%20x__xgafv%3DNone),-Adds%20a%20user), for the method `insert` the email must be unique, but I'm not familiar with Google Discovery and if its methods actually reflects all the possibilities to interact with Google's services.

Help?